# Rename the bunch of files with a specific pattern

Tags: files, rename

I have number of files with following name details..

```
2007-07-22-2300-11S.NAN___024_ABI___HH_E_SAC
```

Where:

- `2007-07-22` is date.
- `2300-11S` is hhmm-sec.
- `NAN___024` is network same for each file (not required in new name).
- `ABI__HH_E`  is station name with East channel.
- `SAC` is extension.

And, I want to rename all files in following same format:

```
2007.204.23.00.ABI.e
```

Where:

- `2007` is year.
- `204` is julian day (of 07-22).
- `23.00` is time.
- `ABI` is station.
- `e` is channel name.

Comment: Julian Day 204 was in 4713 BCE; I think you meant the ordinal date. In which case, see `date +%j`—though that gives 203, not 204 for 2007-07-22. Please explain how your "julian day" is calculated. (Do you count all years as leap years or something like that?)

Comment: Paste the script or one liner, which you have tried so far

Answer (score 1):

For mass renaming, `prename` is your friend. In this case:

```
prename 's/^(\d*)-(\d*-\d*)-(\d*)-.*___\d*_(\w*)___\w*_(\w*)_\w*/$1.$2.$3.$4.$5/' *
```

(ignoring the Julian date until the respective questions have been clarified).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you:

- wanted "1 + Ordinal date" at Position 2.
- "_"-padded station names.
- lowercasing of the channel name

Then this should perform the wanted transform.

```
$ ls
2007-07-22-2300-11S.NAN___024_ABI___HH_E_SAC
$ for i in *; do
    od="$(expr $(date +%j -d "${i:0:10}") + 1 )";
    chn="${i:39:1}";
    sta="$(echo ${i:30:6} | tr -d '_')";
    mv "$i" "${i:0:4}.$od.${i:11:2}.${i:13:2}.$sta.${chn,,}" ;
  done 
$ ls
2007.204.23.00.ABI.e
```